# List of an entity creates a separate table rather than being included with the entity itself

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

When I put a list of Automobiles as an attribute of an entity called, "Loaner Car", and the relationship is one to many to it's parent class called, "Automobile" it creates an a separate table rather than persisting it as one entity. I know that mysql is a single key and single value database, so is it possible for it to intake complex structures, like a list. I've tried using @Embeddable but since I have a list of Automobiles, which is the parent class of LoanerCar, it prevents me from making the parent class embeddable within the child class. Is there anything I can do for this?
Here's my code...

**Automobile.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Automobile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    @OneToOne
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @OneToOne
    private AutomobileType autotype;

    @OneToOne
    private LoanerCar loanerCarID;

    private String vin;

    //Getters and Setters, No-Arg Constructor, etc..
}
```

**LoanerCar.java**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class LoanerCar extends Automobile{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private Timestamp dateLoaned;

    private Timestamp dateReceived;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Automobile> alist;

    //Getters and Setters, No-Arg Constructor, etc.
    }
```

**TotaledCar.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class TotaledCar extends Automobile {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany
    private List<LoanerCar> eligibleLoaners;

    //Getters and Setters, No-Arg Constructor, etc..

}
```

After executing this code the output of tables shows this...

[image: Output of Tables created]

It creates a table for the list elements of the entities, "TotaledCar" and "LoanerCar." I would like for every row in the TotaledCar table to have a list of  elements. And based off that row, I can retrieve, update, add a value within that list. But the main thing is for all the attribute of each entity to be within grouped into there corresponding table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets cover two things here given that your question is somwhat vague and I want to make sure we clarify both in case your confusion lies with one or the other or even both.

**Inheritance**

Your entity setup is one that uses entity inheritance.  You essentially have said you have an abstract base class called `Automobile` and two specializations called `TotaledCar` and `LoanerCar`.  Each of these entity types contain a series of attributes that the subclasses inherit.

The question is how to model this at the database level.

Your existing code uses the `JOINED`  strategy which means each entity's attributes will be spread across a table for each entity type, therefore you end up with a table for `Automobile`, `TotaledCar`, and `LoanerCar`.

From a design point of view, this may not necessarily be a bad choice.  I'll explain more why after covering the other types.

Another alternative is `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy.  In this case, you end up with a table likely called `Automobile` where attributes from all **basic** types are stored in a single row.  I explicitly mention basic types because I'm not talking about associations, those marked as `...ToMany`.  We'll cover those later too.

The other alternative is `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy.  In this case, you end up with a table for each automobile car type, but rather than sharing the common attributes of `Automobile` in a separate table like `JOINED` does, you'll end up duplicating those columns in each concrete subclass.  Therefore, you'd see a column for `VIN` in both `TotaledCar` and `LoanerCar`.

The choice of which strategy to use is highly dependent on your application's needs and the amount of data you'll be dealing with.  With `JOINED` you eliminate any potential overhead on storage that you have with `SINGLE_TABLE` but you incur the join-cost at query-time.  For `TABLE_PER_CLASS`, you avoid the join-cost and the storage overhead and gain all the benefits at the code level with inheritance.

**Associations**

Depending on the association mapping, there are cases where the association will be inlined (attached) with the entity's table.  These are mappings such as `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne`.  For these cases, the primary key of the associated entity will be stored as column(s) in the current table.

For `@OneToMany`, the associated entity type typically owns the association and therefore will be the table that manages the foreign key relationship to the current entity.  You can however make `@OneToMany` associations own the relationship and in these cases, you do this using a join-table.

For `@ManyToMany`, neither entity table will inline the relationship.  This mapping table will require the use of a join-table that stores the primary keys for each entity type as a single-row per entry.

For `@ElementCollection`, these will also be managed in a join-table.